# How to import multiple ui libraries using fixBabelImports in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, antd, babel-plugin

I'm trying to use two ant design ui libraries together with fixBabelImports namely [Ant Design(for desktop browser)](https://ant.design/) and [Ant Design Mobile(for mobile browser)](https://mobile.ant.design/). I tried the following methods, both works without console error, but i'm not sure which method is correct.

Method 1

```js
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra');

const theme = require('./package.json').theme;

module.exports = override( 
    fixBabelImports('antd', {
        libraryName: 'antd',
        libraryDirectory: 'es',    
        style: true,
      }),
    fixBabelImports('import', {
        libraryName: 'antd-mobile',
        style: true
    }), 
    addLessLoader({
        javascriptEnabled: true        
    })
);
```

Method 2

```js
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra');

const theme = require('./package.json').theme;

module.exports = override(     
    fixBabelImports('import', {
        libraryName: ['antd-mobile', 'antd'],
        style: true
    }), 
    addLessLoader({
        javascriptEnabled: true
    })
);
```

Comment: Hi, did you get an answer? I'm trying to import antd and prismjs but can't seem to get them to work

Answer (score 0):

Accord to the customize-cra's [API docs](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/blob/master/api.md#addexternalbabelpluginsplugins), method 1 is right.

The example of addExternalBabelPlugins(plugins) in the doc:

```
module.exports = override(
  disableEsLint(),
  ...addExternalBabelPlugins(
    "babel-plugin-transform-do-expressions",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ),
  fixBabelImports("lodash", {
    libraryDirectory: "",
    camel2DashComponentName: false
  }),
  fixBabelImports("react-feather", {
    libraryName: "react-feather",
    libraryDirectory: "dist/icons"
  })
);
```